# How can i write remove method using java?

Tags: java, arrays, string

**I need to remove the value .**
*see insert method - *

```
@Override
public void insertFaculty(Faculty e) {          
    setFaculty(e);

    list.add(e.getname());
    list.add(e.getfid());
    list.add(Double.toString(e.getsalary()));

    System.out.println("\n\nFaculty inserted sucessfully.");    
}
```

**Now I need to remove the value that was input from my insert method**
*I have try removed method but does not work(⊙_⊙;) *

```
@Override
public void removeFaculty(Faculty e) {   
      int i;

      for(i = 1;i<list.size();i=i+1) {
          System.out.println(list.get(i));
          if(e.fid.equals(list.get(i))) {
              System.out.println("Match found .");
              list.remove(i-1);
              list.remove(i);
              list.remove(i+1);
          }
          else {
              System.out.println("Not found .");
          }
      }                     
  }
```

Comment: why you create list<String> like that? why not use list<Faculty>?

Comment: Removing from a container while iterating over it is generally a bad practice.  The typical approach is to identify which elements need to removed in one loop, then remove them in a second loop.  Put the identified elements in another container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider that when you remove `i-1`, everything shifts along by 1. So, the thing that was previously at `i` is now at `i-1`. And if you remove that one, the thing initially at `i+1` will then be at `i-1`.

So, you could remove `i-1` 3 times:

```
// Or use a for loop.
list.remove(i-1);
list.remove(i-1);
list.remove(i-1);
```

Or reverse the order of the removals:

```
list.remove(i+1);
list.remove(i);
list.remove(i-1);
```

Or clear a sublist:

```
list.subList(i-1, i+2).clear();
```

And don't forget to decrement `i` by one, so you will check the "new" thing at `i` on the next iteration (or break, if you only needed to find one thing).

---

All of this said, it looks like you are throwing related data of unrelated types into the same list.

You're also checking all elements in the list - but only one in three are ids. For one thing, you could just check element 1, 4, 7 etc. I don't know what the type of the id is, but in general you could find a value equal to the id in a "non-id position" (0, 2, 3, 5 etc), and removing that element and the adjacent elements would corrupt your list.

Instead of doing that, create a class to hold your three fields. Create an instance of that, and add it to the list (or just store your `Faculty` objects directly).

Answer (score 1):

```
    @Override
    public void removeFaculty(Faculty e) {          
    setFaculty(e);

    list.remove(e.getname());
    list.remove(e.getfid());
    list.remove(Double.toString(e.getsalary()));
    System.out.println("\n\nFaculty Removed sucessfully.");    
}
```

You can use `remove` method list for removing. You need pass element which you want to remove.

Its better if you use `list<Faculty>` instead of `list<String>`.

```
List<Faculty> list= new ArrayList<Faculty>();
```

Hope, this will helps you.

Answer (score 1):

There are different *logical errors* in your code:

1. Your index should not be increased by 1, but by 3;
2. When you remove items from the list, you don't have to increase the index.

Try this code:

```
@Override
public void removeFaculty(Faculty e) {
    int i = 1;

    while(i<list.size()) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
        if(e.fid.equals(list.get(i))) {
            System.out.println("Match found.");
            list.remove(i-1);
            list.remove(i-1);
            list.remove(i-1);
        } else {
            i+=3;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1 doesn't matter if you do 2, because the id is at elements 1, 4, 7 etc.

Comment: Have you ever heard of computational efficiency? ;)

Answer (score 1):

1. If only 3 elements in your list then list size should be 3;
2. list.get() method returns the element at the specified position in this list. 
   but you didn't define the type of the list. So no idea which type of returns. I assumed that the type is `Object`
3. if there is only one list then no need to call loop.
4. Use the list as `List<Faculty>` rather than `List<Object>`

---

```
@Override 
public void removeFaculty(Faculty e) {   
          System.out.println(list.get(1));

          if(e.fid.equals(list.get(1)) {

              System.out.println("Match found .");
            list.subList(0, list.size()-1).clear();
         }
           else {
              System.out.println("Not found .");
          }


               }
```

Comment: Why are you sure that there is only three elements in the list, method insertFaculty might be called several times

Comment: yes. there is a little bit of confusion in his code. if he need like that he can go with List<Faculty>

Answer (score 0):

Remove at index `i` twice and `i-1` once, will remove the `id`, `salary`, and `name`.

After the first deletion, the element at index `i+1` will be `i` sand will remain `i-1`

```
list.remove(i);
list.remove(i);
list.remove(i - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that List.remove is shifting all the elements back to fill the hole left when you do `list.remove(i-1)`, so the fix is to call list.remove(i-1) three times instead of calling it with i-1, i, and i+1.

But you really should be inserting the Faculty object into the list instead of its three fields independently. Use the generic List and list.add(e) in your insertFaculty method. Then a single call to list.remove in your removeFaculty method.